Change colors in draw.io
I'm trying to get a completely red color in draw.io.
But I can only seem to get this redish-pink thing.
I've set opacity to 100% and tried to press different styles but no change occurs.


Switch to Light mode.
On Dark mode, draw.io uses a different color palette.









Light Mode
Dark Mode



The Light/Dark Mode can be switched from the upper-right corner by clicking the Sun/Moon icon.









Light Mode (Sun)
Dark Mode (Moon)



